# How to create a .NET assembly with a strong name programmatically?

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, assemblies, strongname

Is there a way to create a strong-named assembly using CSharpCodeProvider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See SN.EXE ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k5b5tt23(VS.80).aspx ).  You'll have to execute that on your assembly pointing to a key file to do the signing.

Comment: Is it redistributable tool or part of .Net framework? I want to use it on a client machine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure MS doesn't care if you redistribute it.  Not sure if it comes with the framework or not.  It appears to come with the Microsoft SDKs (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin).  I don't find that file on a machine without a development environment.

Comment: If you want to use it on a client machine, your bigger architectural issue - still I would not take redistribution of tools that are not allowed to lightly - is that you need to "ship" your key file. That renders part of strong naming useless.

Comment: I have to create SQLCLR stored procedures dynamically for optimization purposes. Fortunately, I can CREATE ASSEMBLY even if the assembly has not strong name, if PERMISSION_SET is SAFE. So, I take the whole question back. Nevertheless, now I know for sure I cannot create strong-named assemblies on a client machine without sn.exe or obsolete API. Hate the strong names, .snk, security schemas etc. etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could also specify the /keyfile: option in the CompilerOptions property of the CompilerParameters you send to the CSharpCodeProvider when compiling.